# Ionic / Angular - ngFor hand over item.id on (click) event

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an  list and I want to change the height of the card when I click on a button (the button is on the card) but, how I do this?

I try to hand over the item.id on a click event and use the id in the function but i get an error when i want to use `(click="details({{item.id}})"`.

So how i can solve the problem?

here the html code:

```
 <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content class="date-card">
        <h1 class="date">{{date}}</h1>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" id="{{item.id}}" >
  <ion-card-content class="content-box">
    <ion-card-title class="title">{{item.label}}</ion-card-title>
    <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="time" ></ion-icon>  {{item.time_start}}</h2>
    <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="calendar" ></ion-icon>  {{item.date_start}}</h2>
    <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="compass" ></ion-icon>  {{item.location_text}}</h2>
  </ion-card-content>
  <div class="icon-div">
    <button class="icon-button">
      <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="star"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button class="icon-button" (click)="details()">
      <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="arrow-down" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button class="icon-button">
      <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="share"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-card>
```

And sorry for my bad english^^

Comment: (click)="details(item.id)" is the right syntax

Comment: You don't need to put item.id inside the double-curly braces for interpolation. (click)="details(item.id)"

Comment: This is basic things of angular... please refer official doc first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it without the curly brackets

```
(click)="details(item.id)".
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in the scope of ngFor so you can use item variable , as long you are in ion-card body you can use item variable

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" id="{{item.id}}" >
  ...
      <button class="icon-button" (click)="details(item.id)">
        <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="arrow-down" ></ion-icon>
      </button>
...
</ion-card>
```

[ngFor Local variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You are in the scope of ngFor so you can use item variable

```
<ion-card>
        <ion-card-content class="date-card">
            <h1 class="date">{{date}}</h1>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" **[id]="item.id"** >
      <ion-card-content class="content-box">
        <ion-card-title class="title">{{item.label}}</ion-card-title>
        <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="time" ></ion-icon>  {{item.time_start}}</h2>
        <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="calendar" ></ion-icon>  {{item.date_start}}</h2>
        <h2 class="md-text"><ion-icon name="compass" ></ion-icon>  {{item.location_text}}</h2>
      </ion-card-content>
      <div class="icon-div">
        <button class="icon-button">
          <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="star"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="icon-button" **(click)="details(item.id)"**>
          <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="arrow-down" ></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="icon-button">
          <ion-icon class="icon-button-icon" name="share"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-card>
```